The control function is not sending out correct values
#include <MIDI.h>

int scale = A4;
int oct = A2;
int potval, octval,octval2=0;
int newnote, prevnote = -1;
int newpotval,prepotval=-1,potval2=0;
int trigr = 7;   // Ultrasonic right
int echor = 9;
int trigl = 8;   // Ultrasonic left
int echol = 10;
int pingr,pingr1=0, pingl,pingl1=0, cc, octave, p;
int button = 13; // Button
int buttonval = 0;

MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

void setup() {
  pinMode(scale, INPUT);
  pinMode(oct, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigr, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echor, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigl, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echol, INPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);

  //MIDI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  potval = analogRead(scale);
  delay(5);
  octval = analogRead(oct);
  delay(5);
  octave = octavenum(octval);
  p=scaleval(potval,potval2);
  Serial.println(p);
  delay(50);

  control();
  delay(50);
  //notesscale(p);
  //delay(50);
}
void notesscale(int p) {
  digitalWrite(trigr, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(30);
  digitalWrite(trigr, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(30);
  digitalWrite(trigr, LOW);

  pingr = pulseIn(echor, HIGH);

  Serial.print("Right ultrasonic values: ");
  Serial.println(pingr);
  delay(100);

  if(abs(pingr - pingr1) > 200) {
    if (pingr <= 850) {            // Condition 1
      newnote = p;
    } 
    else if (pingr <= 1450) {       // Condition 2
      newnote = p + 2;
    } 
    else if (pingr <= 2050) {       // Condition 3
      newnote = p + 4;
    } 
    else if (pingr <= 2650) {      // Condition 4
      newnote = p + 5;
    } 
    else if (pingr <= 3250) {      // Condition 5
      newnote = p + 7;
    } 
    else if (pingr <= 3850) {      // Condition 6
      newnote = p + 9;
    } 
    else if (pingr <= 4450) {      // Condition 7
      newnote = p + 11;
    } 
    else if (pingr <= 5050) {      // Condition 8
      newnote = p + 12;
    } else {
      newnote = -1;
    }

    if (prevnote != newnote) {  // Ensure newnote is valid
      if (prevnote != -1) {
        MIDI.sendNoteOff(prevnote, 127, 1);
        delay(20); // Adjust delay if needed
      }
      MIDI.sendNoteOn(newnote, 127, 1);
      delay(20);
      prevnote = newnote;
    }
    pingr1 = pingr;
    delay(10);
  }
}
int octavenum(int octval) {
  if(abs(octval-octval2)>20){
    if (octval >= 0 && octval <= 93) {
      octval2=octval;
      return -2;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 94 && octval <= 186) {
      octval2=octval;
      return -1;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 187 && octval <= 279) {
      octval2=octval;
      return 0;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 280 && octval <= 372) {
      octval2=octval;
      return 1;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 373 && octval <= 465) {
      octval2=octval;
      return 2;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 466 && octval <= 558) {
      octval2=octval;
      return 3;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 559 && octval <= 651) {
      octval2=octval;
      return 4;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 652 && octval <= 744) {
      octval2=octval;
      return 5;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 745 && octval <= 837) {
      return 6;
    } 
    else if (octval >= 838 && octval <= 930) {
      octval2=octval;
      return 7;
    } 
    else {
      octval2=octval;
      return 8;
    }

  }
  return octval2;

}


int octaveOffset(int octave, int baseNote) {
  return baseNote + (octave + 2) * 12;
}

void control() {
  digitalWrite(trigl, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(20);
  digitalWrite(trigl, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(20);
  digitalWrite(trigl, LOW);
  pingl = pulseIn(echol, HIGH);

  Serial.println("left ultrasonic values");
  Serial.println(pingl);

  if (pingl >= 0 && pingl < 250) {
    MIDI.sendControlChange(14, 0, 1);  // (cc channel, cc value, channel)
  } 
  else if (pingl > 2000 && pingl < 4000) {
    MIDI.sendControlChange(14, 127, 1);
  } 
  else if (pingl >= 250 && pingl <= 2000) {
    cc = abs((127.0 / 1750.0) * (pingl - 250));
    MIDI.sendControlChange(14, cc, 1);
  }
  else if(pingl>5000){
    
  }
  delay(10);
}


int scaleval(int potval,int potval2){
  if(abs(potval-potval2)>50){
    if (potval <= 86) {
      Serial.println("C maj/A min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 0);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 172) {
      Serial.println("C# maj");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 1);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 258) {
      Serial.println("D maj");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 2);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 344) {
      Serial.println("D# maj/C min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 3);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 430) {
      Serial.println("E maj/C# min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 4);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 516) {
      Serial.println("F maj/D min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 5);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 602) {
      Serial.println("F# maj/D# min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 6);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 688) {
      Serial.println("G maj/E min");
      newpotval= octaveOffset(octave, 7);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 774) {
      Serial.println("G# maj/F min");
      newpotval= octaveOffset(octave, 8);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 860) {
      Serial.println("A maj/F# min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 9);
    } 
    else if (potval <= 946) {
      Serial.println("A# maj/G min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 10);
    } 
    else {
      Serial.println("B maj/G# min");
      newpotval = octaveOffset(octave, 11);
    }
    if (newpotval != prepotval) { 
      prepotval = newpotval;
      return newpotval;
    }
    potval2=potval;
    return prepotval;
  }
}

/// the correct output that is required is different values ranging from 0 to 127 outputted through midi cc 14 but when the control() function is being called then the program outputs random values through random midi cc channels the other functions are outputting correct values which are  called prior to control(),also i monitored the outputs using the serial monitor which gave me correct values for the octave and p and the distance measured using ultrasonic sensor.Also when i am using hairless serial-midi converter to monitor my midi messages.

Sorry, a code-only question nearly always has too few information. What do you mean by "correct" and "not correct"? Where is it sending the values? How do you check on the send values? How do you know the inputs are correct? What exactly is the input in your code? What have you done to narrow down the problem? Please add some text to your question (by editing it, not in the comments) to answer these questions. That might enable us to help you.

looks like the octavenum() function was written by a different person than scaleval() ... octavenum() has more cumbersome logic, with unnecessary  code ... scaleval() is more elegant in its logic, with simpler code .... octavenum() could easily be the same way

when the function is being called ... which function? ... please clarify exactly what the program is doing ... the other functions are outputting correct values ... which functions?

reduce your code ... send some fixed values ... do you receive those values correctly?

cc = abs((127.0 / 1750.0) * (pingl - 250)); With some boards abs() does not work correctly on floats. See https://forum.arduino.cc/t/abs-function-does-apparently-not-work-on-floats/658747/ . It may not be your problem and may not be your board.

pingl = pulseIn(echol, HIGH); This may be a problem depending on which board you have since pingl is defined as int which may overflow after about 32,000 (us) on an 8bit cpu. (pulseIn returns microseconds and, by default, times out at 1 second).  It is probably best to define pingl as unsigned long (uint32_t)

Agreed with @6v6gt, pulseIn() return duration in uS with unsigned long which is 32-bit, not a 16-bit int.
